# I am running into errors when trying to create an anaconda environment for gaussian splatting

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to run gaussian splatting locally on my computer using jonstephens version on github. I followed all the steps with installing all the prereqs but when i am trying to create the environment, i am getting errors with installing diff_gaussian_rasterization simple_knn. It comes with the error "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdefs.h': No such file or directory" and "The detected CUDA version (11.8) has a minor version mismatch with the version that was used to compile PyTorch (11.6). Most likely this shouldn't be a problem."

I have tried updating all in conda, uninstalling and reinstalling visual studio for the cpp build tools and making sure my CUDA version is what is recommended (11.8). Before i was having an error with cl.exe when installing simple_knn but i added it to my path in environment and now that error is gone but now I have this new error. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling pytorch in base with 11.8 cuda

```
git clone github.com/graphdeco-inria/gaussian-splatting --recursive 
SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1 
conda env create --file environment.yml






[3/3] C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc --generate-dependencies-with-compile --dependency-output C:\Users\user\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\spatial.obj.d --use-local-env -Xcompiler /MD -Xcompiler /wd4819 -Xcompiler /wd4251 -Xcompiler /wd4244 -Xcompiler /wd4267 -Xcompiler /wd4275 -Xcompiler /wd4018 -Xcompiler /wd4190 -Xcompiler /EHsc -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=base_class_has_different_dll_interface -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=field_without_dll_interface -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_none_assumed -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_dllexport_assumed -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\include -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\csrc\api\include -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\include\TH -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\include\THC "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include" -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\include -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\Include -c C:\Users\user\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn\spatial.cu -o C:\Users\user\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\spatial.obj -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_C -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=compute_86 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=sm_86
      FAILED: C:/Users/user/gaussian-splatting/submodules/simple-knn/build/temp.win-amd64-cpython-37/Release/spatial.obj
      C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin\nvcc --generate-dependencies-with-compile --dependency-output C:\Users\user\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\spatial.obj.d --use-local-env -Xcompiler /MD -Xcompiler /wd4819 -Xcompiler /wd4251 -Xcompiler /wd4244 -Xcompiler /wd4267 -Xcompiler /wd4275 -Xcompiler /wd4018 -Xcompiler /wd4190 -Xcompiler /EHsc -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=base_class_has_different_dll_interface -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=field_without_dll_interface -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_none_assumed -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_dllexport_assumed -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\include -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\include\torch\csrc\api\include -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\include\TH -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\include\THC "-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include" -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\include -IC:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\Include -c C:\Users\user\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn\spatial.cu -o C:\Users\user\gaussian-splatting\submodules\simple-knn\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\spatial.obj -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ --expt-relaxed-constexpr -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_C -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=compute_86 -gencode=arch=compute_86,code=sm_86
      C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\include\crt/host_config.h(231): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdefs.h': No such file or directory

      spatial.cu

      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1814, in _run_ninja_build
          env=env)
        File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\gaussian_splatting\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
          output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
      [end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> simple_knn

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Comment: Please include the steps you took, i.e. commands you ran to create your environment and install packages to it

Comment: git clone https://github.com/graphdeco-inria/gaussian-splatting --recursive
SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
conda env create --file environment.yml
after i try to create the enviroment it fails with error
× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> simple_knn

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

Comment: Please use the [edit] feature to add information.

Comment: i added in the steps i took and part of the error message